# How do I not only move a control's location but also, change it's axis?

Tags: silverlight, rotation, move

I am making a phone application in Silverlight, Windows Mobile.

I am able to change the location of a button, or a label etc.  That's fine and all good.

However, does anyone know how I can change the actual axis, as in, rotation.  For example: | in to __ ?

Let's say that: | .... is a button or something.  I can move it around the screen with ease.

But how do I make it from | and change the rotation to __ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RotateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.aspx) in your XAML or as a method in the code-behind.

This is the example that is listed on the linked page:

```
<Canvas Height="200" Width="200">
  <Polyline Points="25,25 0,50 25,75 50,50 25,25 25,0" 
    Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="10"
    Canvas.Left="75" Canvas.Top="50">
    <Polyline.RenderTransform>
      <RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="45" />
    </Polyline.RenderTransform>
  </Polyline>
</Canvas>
```

Hope this helps

Edit: Code behind example doing exactly the same thing as XAML:

```
Polyline polyline1 = new Polyline();
polyline1.Points.Add(new Point(25, 25));
polyline1.Points.Add(new Point(0, 50));
polyline1.Points.Add(new Point(25, 75));
polyline1.Points.Add(new Point(50, 50));
polyline1.Points.Add(new Point(25, 25));
polyline1.Points.Add(new Point(25, 0));
polyline1.Stroke = Brushes.Blue;
polyline1.StrokeThickness = 10;
RotateTransform rotateTransform1 = new RotateTransform(45);
polyline1.RenderTransform = rotateTransform1;
```

Comment: Hi Dane. Thank you so much for replying. Can you please show me how I can do this in code? As in, in a method, please. With a button,

Comment: Ahah. Okay this makes sense! I am going to try it now!

Comment: Hi Dane! I GOT IT WORKING! But....It's spinning off the top left hand corner. Do you know how I can make it spin from the center? Thank you!

Comment: OMG! I GOT IT WORKING! I basically did: rotateTransform.CenterX = button1.Width / 2;
rotateTransform.CenterY = button1.Height / 2; Thank you so much Dane!!!